# Чат бот на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, чат

Начинаю програмировать ра Питоне, узнал что есть такая волшебная штука как чат бот. Объясните мне пожалуйста какой функцией вызывается, как его надо настраивать, а за одно и про `def`.
Заранее спасбо!
Если подобный вопос уже задавали, напишите ссылку.

Comment: И в каком же источнике Вы такое узнали?

Comment: Увидел вопрос (здесь) тоже про чат-бота, но там было друое.

Comment: Пройдите кокой нибудь курс по Python

Comment: Например????????

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему... а вообще стыдно должно быть задавать такие вопросы... и уж тем более не зная даже основ языка лезть в создание чат ботов и тд.. "учи матчасть, сынок"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чат бот для чего? Телеграм, ВК? Вы можете использовать библиотеки vk_api, telegram_api соответственно. Подробные уроки давно лежат в ютубе. def это функция, принимающая и отдающая аргументы.

Пример функции:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Пример работы:

```
>>> add(1, 10)
11
>>> add('abc', 'def')
'abcdef'
```

Comment: Нет, не для соц сетей (вы меня ни-где не найдёте), просто хочу тупо на питоне, простенькую программу.

Comment: @Данилкн PUBG Про def так ничего и не понял...

Comment: Можно чють по подробнее?

Comment: `def` это `define`, а не функция.. функция это лишь абстракция в ЯП